# Can someone help me fix this code

Tags: java, android

Please help fix this i wont load the `SharedPreferences`
if you can please post a reply with the code in it please
its just a clicking app and i want it to save the score from the clicks
everytime it just loads from 0 please help me fix the code

```
import android.R.string;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    int counter;
    Button add;
    TextView display;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        LoadPrefs();
        counter = 0;
        add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                counter++;
                display.setText("You Have " + counter);
                SavePrefs("click", display.getText().toString());
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;

    }


    private void LoadPrefs(){
        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        String name = sp.getString("click", "You Have zero");

}

    private void SavePrefs(String key, boolean value){
        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        Editor edit = sp.edit();
        edit.putBoolean(key, value);
        edit.commit();

}

    private void SavePrefs(String key, String value){
        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        Editor edit = sp.edit();
        edit.putString("click", "You Have zero");
        edit.commit();

}

}
```

Comment: We are not a code debugging service. You should at least tell us what you've tried yourself, so we don't waste OUR time duplicating things YOU should have tried already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting `counter` to 0 after calling `LoadPrefs`. Also, you are not setting `counter` when you load the preferences.

In order to save an actual `int` value (instead of the display string) and to keep the display and the saved value in synch, I'd do it something like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    int counter;
    Button add;
    TextView display;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setCounter(counter + 1);
            }
        });
        display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        loadCounter(); // must come after display is assigned
    }

    private void loadCounter(){
        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        setCounter(sp.getInt("click", 0));
    }

    private void setCounter(int value) {
        counter = value;
        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        Editor edit = sp.edit();
        edit.put("click", counter);
        edit.apply(); // apply() is better than commit()
        display.setText("You Have " +
            (counter > 0 ? String.valueOf(counter) : "zero");
    }
}
```

Comment: can you type in the counter in the code dont understand where i gonna put it

Comment: @user3204046 - I don't understand your comment. I'd suggest changing your design to store an `int` instead of a `String` in the prefs. Then you can use `-1` (instead of `"You Have zero"`) as the default value. You can also load the value into `counter` instead of initializing `counter` to 0 in `onCreate()`.

Comment: can you please copy and change the java and then paste in the fixed way i dont understand how to even put the string as a int

Comment: @user3204046 - I posted some code showing how I might implement the functionality you want.

Comment: Thanks so much someone that understand im new to this and only 13 years old

Comment: @user3204046 - Glad I could help. Good luck with your project!